# UWP: Creating an accessible WebView

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, accessibility

I'm using a webview inside my app that contains text. It's easy this way, because many things are already available (zooming in, copying text etc.). The only problem is that it has to be accessible for screen readers such as jaws, narrator, ...

I managed to let the screenreader read the content of the webview by making the html accessible (using a  tag for my content), but before the content is told to the user, the screenreader reads the url of the page which is about:blank.

Is there somekind of (maybe hacky) solution to block the screenreader from telling the url to the user?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is, but it's bad practice anyway. All you'd do is skip an expected behavior, which may lead people to think their device is malfunctioning.

Kudos on thinking about accessibility though.

Comment: Thx, i know but it shouldn't appear to the user as a webview, i just use it as a container for text, that's why i don't want to tell the user the url